# REGEX That Doesn't Allow Spaces or Special Characters

Tags: regex, xenforo

Salutations, I need a regular expression in which doesn't allow spaces or special characters. All replies are appreciated. Thank you.

For example, if somebody enters `$cdIAb!%`, `a bcd`, or `$ab%c d@`, it would be rejected. If they entered `cdIAb` it would be accepted.

This is for an Xenforo forum.

Comment: Knowing the problem is essential to its solution. Please be a bit more concise.

Comment: Please provide an example of the input and what you expect as the result. Please also indicate the environment (language) in which you're running the regex.

Comment: I've added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex express you would use is `^(\d|\w)+$`:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^(\d|\w)+$">
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cD3LhM/1) example.

Answer (score 0):

Search for this:

`/[^A-Za-z0-9]/`

If the search is positive, reject.